# select2 Clear Search Input

Tags: select, jquery-select2

I have problems with my Select2 filters.
I need to implement Clear button. I have 4 filters, two of them are simple select filters, and two are inputs with search bar that are developed through query parameter of select2.js

```
<div class="input-append">
  <select class="filter-select form-control data-filter fCombo-select">
    <option></option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="input-append">
  <input type="hidden" class="fCombo-select"/>
</div>

_this.$s('input.fCombo-select').select2(params);
_this.$s('select.fCombo-select').select2(params);
```

When I make select2 filters from that ones everything is fine, but I can't clear them correctly.

Using:

```
_this.$s('.fCombo-select').val(value).trigger('change');
```

works fine only on simple select filters. Those that are with search bar I can't clear at all.

Almost the same problem I have with setting the value to these filters. I can't set value for select filters, but those that are with search bar everything is fine.
Please help me, because I am a bit confused and I've tried many thing but they don't work at all.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that solution:
Strange, but I can clear that items only using that

```
$('.customer .fCombo-select').select2('data',null).trigger('change');
```

Why there are too many ways of clearing data? And why these search bars can be cleaned only using that?